# Valuation of Fixed-Income Securities

Tags: fixed-income

[image: Observed prices questions]

Could one of you please assist with question 4 shown in the image above?

Thank you in advance!
JR

Comment: I am voting to close this question for being too basic. It also shows no effort whatsoever.

Comment: Hey LocalVolatility, we all have to start some where.

Comment: Please see https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for what is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonds X and Y pay semiannual coupons. Then the cash flow for X is a single payment at the maturity of 3\$ (half of 6\$ since it's semiannual) plus the par value. The discounted cash flow has to equal the price of the bond. 
Then you have :$$100,98 = \frac{103}{1+R_{0.5}}$$
Solving for $R_{0.5}$ gives you 2%

Then you can perform the same calculation for Y, knowing that you have a first cash flow of 4\$ (that has to be discounted with $R_{0.5}$) for the first 6-month period and a second for the second period for the coupon and the principal payment (that should be discounted with $R_1$).

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could "add a comment" to your answer but I can't for the moment.
Of course, the coupon for Y is 4\$ I corrected my answer. However, you are missing to square the denominator (because you are discounting the cash flow of the second period). You should have : $$103.59 = \frac{4}{1+R_{0.5}} + \frac{104}{(1+R_1)^2}$$
Since you know $R_{0.5}$ you can solve for $R_{1}$. 
Hope this helped!